# I want numeric count for checked box but i am getting array of values

Tags: jquery

```
 $("#UserOrgId").find("span.ms-RadioText > input").each(function()
 {
    console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
 }
 )
```

//Provides me 23 rows with true false value but i want count of trues only i.e. if

//Out of 23, 2 are true, I want output as 2

Comment: How does it get related to SharePoint?

Comment: i am trying to count number of true checkboxes and linking it to condition for a field in sharepoint designer new form in advanced mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var count = 0;

$("#UserOrgId").find("span.ms-RadioText > input").each(function() {
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        count += 1;
    }
});

console.log(count);
```

Comment: not working..in console,it says 'object doesnt support property of prop method

Comment: whoops, now try.

Comment: when i use code in console, it give me  output as "undefined 3(number of trues)"